S/MIME Email Sent via Python and Microsoft Graph Works in Gmail but Not in Outlook
I was trying to send an S/MIME email created in Python using Microsoft Graph. The email was sent successfully, and both Gmail and the iOS Mail app on my iPhone recognized the sender as trusted with a valid certificate. Everything seemed fine on those platforms.
However, when I opened the same email in Outlook, I encountered the following issues:

Outlook displayed a warning stating that the certificate had an issue and the content may have been altered.
The email content was converted into an attachment named winmail.dat (Content-Type: application/ms-tnef).
The S/MIME signature was not displayed properly, and the email failed DKIM and DMARC checks (dkim=none, dmarc=none).

This behavior is puzzling since the email is properly recognized on other platforms. Is there something specific about the way Outlook processes S/MIME emails that could cause this issue? Could this be related to the MIME encoding or formatting when sending the email via Graph API?

What's exactly is the issue?

If you want to write a guide, it needs to be presented as a question and answer: this isn't a forum. Also, you should check whether the question has been asked already, and answer the existing question, if it exists.

@snakecharmerb  Sorry guys, I did edit my question and put the answer.
Thank you for letting me know!

If you're looking to send MIME content (like HTML and plain text) with Microsoft Graph in Python, here’s a guide on how to sign the MIME message with S/MIME and send it to Microsoft Graph. This code demonstrates how to handle OAuth authentication, sign the email using S/MIME, and encode it for Graph API compatibility.
The process requires:

OAuth Token Retrieval: Use a certificate-based credential to
retrieve an access token.
MIME Message Creation: Create a MIME
message with alternative plain text and HTML parts.
S/MIME Signing:
Sign the MIME message with a private key and certificate.
Draft Creation: Create a draft email with the signed MIME content using
Microsoft Graph.

Here's the full code:
from azure.identity import CertificateCredential
from azure.core.credentials import AccessToken
import base64
import httpx
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smail import sign_message

# Step 1: Retrieve OAuth token using Certificate-based credential
def __get_graph_oauth_token(self) -> str:
    credential: CertificateCredential = self.__get_graph_credential()
    token: AccessToken = credential.get_token(self.scope)
    return token.token

def __get_graph_credential(self) -> CertificateCredential:
    crypto_utils: CryptoUtils = CryptoUtils()
    certificate_data: bytes = crypto_utils.get_pfx_certificate(cert_name=self.domain_cert_name)
    return CertificateCredential(
        tenant_id=self.tenant_id,
        client_id=self.client_id,
        certificate_data=certificate_data
    )

# Step 2: Create MIME message with S/MIME signing
def create_signed_mime_message(self, subject: str, body: str, to_email: str, from_email: str):
    # Retrieve the private key, main certificate, and additional certs in PEM format
    private_key_pem, main_certificate_pem, additional_certs_pem = self.__get_auth_priv_rep_certificate_chain()

    # Step 2.1: Create inner alternative part for plain text and HTML
    inner_alternative = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    inner_alternative.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain", "utf-8"))
    inner_alternative.attach(MIMEText(body, "html", "utf-8"))
    inner_alternative["From"] = from_email
    inner_alternative["To"] = to_email
    inner_alternative["Subject"] = subject

    # Step 2.2: Sign the message with temporary key and cert files
    signed_msg = sign_message(
        message=inner_alternative,
        key_signer=private_key_pem,
        cert_signer=main_certificate_pem,
        additional_certs=[additional_certs_pem]
    )
    return signed_msg

# Step 3: Create a draft email with MIME content using Microsoft Graph
async def create_draft_email_with_mime(self, subject: str, body: str, to_email: str):
    access_token: str = self.__get_graph_oauth_token()
    url: str = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{self.from_email}/messages"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Prefer": 'IdType="ImmutableId"'
    }

    # Step 3.1: Create and sign MIME message
    signed_mime_message = self.create_signed_mime_message(
        subject=subject,
        body=body,
        to_email=to_email,
        from_email=self.from_email
    )

    # **CRUCIAL STEP**: Encode the MIME message in base64 and replace line breaks to ensure compatibility with Graph API
    mime_base64 = base64.encodebytes(signed_mime_message.as_string().encode().replace(b'\n', b'\r\n'))


    # Step 3.3: Send the signed MIME content as draft to Microsoft Graph
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, content=mime_base64)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        return response.json()
    else:
        self.logger.error(f"Error creating draft! Status: {response.status_code}. Response: {response.text}")

Explanation

OAuth Token Generation: The function __get_graph_oauth_token fetches the access token required by Microsoft Graph using a certificate-based credential.
S/MIME Signing:

The create_signed_mime_message function creates an alternative MIME message with both plain text and HTML parts.
This message is then signed using sign_message with the appropriate private key and certificate chain in PEM format.


Crucial Base64 Encoding for Graph:

The encoding line mime_base64 = base64.encodebytes(signed_mime_message.as_string().encode().replace(b'\n', b'\r\n')) is essential to ensure compatibility with the Graph API.
Microsoft Graph expects the MIME content in base64 with \r\n line endings, so this adjustment is key for successful transmission.
If this step is not done correctly, Outlook may not interpret the S/MIME signature as intended. Instead, the email can be converted to the winmail.dat format (Content-Type: application/ms-tnef), which is Outlook’s Rich Text Format. This prevents the S/MIME signature from displaying correctly. Additionally, the authentication results may show dkim=none and dmarc=none, indicating that Outlook did not properly interpret the S/MIME signature.



Key Points

S/MIME Signed Message: Signing helps verify the sender's authenticity, and this code ensures MIME content is signed securely.
Async POST Request: Using httpx.AsyncClient for efficient non-blocking HTTP requests.
Error Handling: Error responses from Graph API are logged for troubleshooting.


Microsoft Outlook and Azure logic apps interpret e-mail in a very strict manner.
I ended up using this resource to understand some aspects:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/message-format-and-transmission
What I had trouble with was the strict handling of e-mails being sent by a black box type of software run by another party. They would send an e-mail with text in the body and also have an attachment of the same content. The e-mail had the body text encoded with the same type as the attachment:
Content-Type: text/xml
Outlook and an Azure logic app were strict and interpreted this as an attachment even though it was where the body of a message would go. They auto assigned a filename to the attachment. Thunderbird and Gmail were more relaxed in the handling of the e-mail and when viewing the body section (even through it had a text/xml type, because it was where the body would be, they were more user friendly and interpreted it as plain text and just displayed the XML as the body of the message and then the attachment was handled correctly as an attachment.
My take away is:
It appears Microsoft products are very strict in how they handle messages.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
